# The signature of pandas scatter_matrix method

Tags: python, pandas

```
Signature: pandas.scatter_matrix(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, ax=None, grid=False, diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None, hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds)                                                            
Docstring:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Draw a matrix of scatter plots.
```

In this signature, there is not a 'c' argument, but why I am seeing code in the iris classification exercise, as follows:

```
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15,15), marker='0', hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

Please see the "c=y_train" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c=y_train` is a keyword argument that will get passed to the matplotlib functions.  Python captures it using `**kwds` in the signature.  `c=y_train` will use the data in `y_train` to dictate the color of the data points.

Comment: `c` actually comes from [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) method of matplotlib which are part of the **kwds argument.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, what does the 's' argument come from in the method call? also from **kwds?

Comment: @user697911, Yes, it does. It refers to the size of the scatter points. You can even pass a column to it like you've done for the colors arg. The size would vary based on the value it contains. Refer to the link I've attached before to get all those keyword args.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, in the same exercise, I am seeing this line "print("Test set score: {:.2f}".format(np.mean(y_pred == y_test)))" for evaluating the model. Shouldn't "y_pred==y_test" produce a vector of booleans? How can it calculate its mean?

Comment: @user697911, It's because instances of `bool` become also instances of `int` in Python and hopefully numpy. So, what's happening under the hood is `bool(True)` and `bool(False)`getting converted to 1 and 0 respectively. Try this case:  `np.mean([True, False, True, True])` returns 0.75 (sum of all True values/total number of elements)

Comment: Thank you. Nickil.