# Understanding pandas scatter_matrix argument 'c'

Tags: python, pandas

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905535/the-signature-of-pandas-scatter-matrix-method) link to understand what 'c' means by `c=y_train`. There is an answer that says y_train data will be used to dictate the color. I could not understand this statement.

There is some information in this [documentation link](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) but hard to understand.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When we plot using `grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15,15), marker='0', hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)`, I know iris_dataframe is the dataset in which the variables are going to be plotted but how does y_train dataset contribute to coloring data points? Hope you got the question.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation of matplotlib you linked c is the parameter for the color of the scatter points.

> c can be a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications of length N, or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors using the cmap and norm specified via kwargs

In combination with colormap this will, in your case when c = y_train (the label or ground truth of your data), color your datapoints according to there class (which type of iris flower for the iris data set).